# Azure Cosmos DB - checking container for data before writing it

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I'm moving data from blob storage to cosmos DB using data factory
I have a container with a few thousand rows of data, I would like to load more data to this container but do not want to duplicate any rows. How can I check if that data is already in the container and if so skip that specific data and continue loading?
I'm thinking something along the line of a stored procedure but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Data Flow in Azure Data Factory.

Add two source, one is your Blob Storage container, another one is your destination container in Cosmos DB. Then use [Exists transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-exists). Finally sink to your Cosmos DB container.

**Screenshot of Data Flow:**
[image]